# Typo3 Custom Extension list view BE template doesnt load header

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I have created two extensions using 
[Extension Builder](https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/extension_builder/tree/8.7) on Typo3 8.7.17

For some reason when loading one extension BE page  ddl with overview and Header files are loaded (ie bootstrap / CSS etc), however on the other module only the code for the extension view is loaded and it loads without Bootstrap / CSS / jQuery etc files.

Any ideas anyone

[image: Good Page]

[image: Bad Page]

The listing code is as follows ?

```
<html xmlns:f="https://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
<f:layout name="Default" />

This Template is responsible for creating a table of domain objects.

If you modify this template, do not forget to change the overwrite settings
in /Configuration/ExtensionBuilder/settings.yaml:
  Resources:
    Private:
      Templates:
        List.html: keep

Otherwise your changes will be overwritten the next time you save the extension in the extension builder
<f:section name="content">
    Listing

    <f:for each="{requests}" as="request">
        <div>Stuff</div>
    </f:for>
</f:section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use the backend viewhelper of Fluid, in this case the `f:be.pageRenderer` and `f:be.container` viewhelpers?

PageRenderer: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Be/PageRenderer.html
Container: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Be/Container.html

Comment: You need to wrap it around your content. Easily possible in your layout file.

Comment: brilliant, that was it, also adding the Extension to the Template